# PyWavelets CWT: normalization? Vs Scipy?

Tags: python, dft, convolution, wavelet, pywavelets

[Related](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/70575/50076). The equation being implemented normalizes by `sqrt(1 / scale)`:

$$
C_{a, b} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \sum_k s(k)\left( \int_{-\infty}^{k+1} \overline{\psi \left(\frac{t-b}{a} \right) }dt - \int_{-\infty}^{k} \overline{\psi \left(\frac{t-b}{a} \right) }dt \right)
$$

so why does `pywt._cwt` do [* sqrt(scale)](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/blob/v1.1.1/pywt/_cwt.py#L183)? Also, how is it normalizing (L1, L2, etc)?

---

**Edit**: After reviewing Scipy's [cwt](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/signal/wavelets.py#L469), I realized it's implementing exactly what I described as "ideal" in the answer, thus it's same as comparing the two (except a few obvious details). I don't know in which scenarios pywt's algorithm is better, but generally - <s>easy win for Scipy</s>. I've opened a [PR](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/pull/570) to address pywt's key flaw.

**Edit2**: Found an apparent edge of pywt's over scipy's in the least expected place: [low scales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Udd.png). Addressed [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/70723/50076).

**Edit 3**: after fixing the low `precision` in `pywt`, I actually found `pywt` superior to `scipy` in all of a variety of synthetic signals, but `squeezepy`'s always beat both. Tests [here](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/issues/5), with more coming.

Comment: see also https://github.com/endolith/wavelets (fork of arren) and https://gist.github.com/endolith/2783866 https://gist.github.com/patoorio/a9f60ef16489639fbf20f23ac49ba24f My impression is that scipy's cwt is half-baked

Comment: @endolith Thanks, I might compare later, but from a skim, CWT's normed with `sqrt(dt)`, which is strange. If you're interested in developing CWT and related methods, I invite you to the non-abandoned [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy), which has more features and tests with yet more to come. First pre-release likely tomorrow.

Comment: @endolith Second time I see `jet` rant on a profile, made me look into it. All links broken btw, maybe link [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/223315/239063) instead.

Comment: I forgot that was even in my profile.  I updated the links.

Comment: @endolith One of these days I'll read about the colormaps - until then, for those like me, maybe add "(instead use [turbo](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/08/turbo-improved-rainbow-colormap-for.html))" or alike. Without reading a word I'm nearly sold on it from the article's pics.

Comment: @endolith [Final lobotomy](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86069/50076), with closer look & more knowledge: `pywt < scipy << ssqueezepy`

Comment: @endolith Third jet link's broke. Anywho, if this still concerns you, my tip would be to add an alternative (turbo); I saw your links for two years and simply didn't find it worth bothering with searching alternatives.

Comment: OK I changed the third link to internet archive.  Yes, Turbo is a better rainbow colormap, but Parula and Viridis are now the defaults and are generally recommended as the replacements.

Comment: @endolith That third link to me is strawmanning rainbow, turbo is much better than what it uses. Anyway, I'm saying, even if you're against any rainbow, your odds are improved by pointing to a _better_ rainbow, e.g. adding "(turbo's better, but not best)". Your call of course. And FWIW to me turbo is the best for time-frequency, _once used to_ it; Viridis makes it harder to discriminate intervals near min, median, and max by relying too much on brightness and too little on color. I still want to see [these lows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZoL9.png) easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's follow the math from incubation to delivery. It begins with `psi`, a rescaled [`morlet2`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/signal/wavelets.py#L382) (as shown [previously](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/70640/50076)) at a scale $a=64$, and $\sigma=5$:

$$
\psi = \psi_{\sigma}(t/a) = e^{j\sigma (t/a)} e^{-(t/a)^2/2} \tag{2}
$$

gets [integrated](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/blob/v1.1.1/pywt/_functions.py#L29) and [*L1-normalized*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%7C1%2Fa+*+e+%5E+%28i+*+5+*+x+%2F+a%29+*+e+%5E+%28-%28x%2Fa%29%5E2+%2F+2%29%7C+from+-100+to+100%2C+a+%3D+8): -- (see caveat2 below)

$$
\psi = \psi_{\text{int}}(t) = \frac{1}{a} \int \psi_{\sigma}(t/a)\ dt \tag{3}
$$

The norm is off by a scalar factor, but what matters is it's *same* for different $a$; you can verify it's so (for large $a$, increase integration limits). Note that it's the *wavelet* that's L1-normalized, not the integrated wavelet $\psi_\text{int}(t)$; the distinction is essential, as we'll see.

$\psi$ is then  convolved with the signal $s$, and finite-differenced and negated; from [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70576/50076), this is:

$$
 -\text{DIFF}(\text{conv}) = [s \cdot (\psi_{\text{int}}(t - 0) - \psi_{\text{int}}(t - 1)),\ ...] \tag{4}
$$

Inspecting closely, this is equivalent to undoing the former integration, with certain numeric differences (addressed later), so we're left with

$$
 \psi = \frac{1}{a} \psi_{\sigma}(t/a) \tag{5}
$$

Lastly, [`* sqrt(scale)`](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/blob/v1.1.1/pywt/_cwt.py#L183):

$$
 \boxed{\psi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \psi_{\sigma}(t/a)} \tag{6}
$$

which is thus ultimately *[L2-normalized](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%7C1%2Fsqrt%28a%29+*+e+%5E+%28i+*+5+*+x+%2F+a%29+*+e+%5E+%28-%28x%2Fa%29%5E2+%2F+2%29%7C%5E2+from+-100+to+100%2C+a+%3D+8)*. We can verify this on a test signal; L2 is [biased](http://ocg6.marine.usf.edu/%7Eliu/Papers/Liu_etal_2007_JAOT_wavelet.pdf) in amplitude/power representation toward lower frequencies, suppressing high frequencies. If above is right, not only can we see this, but apply a fix by removing `* sqrt(scale)` from code:

[image]

Implementation-specific caveats discussed next.

---

**How reliable is the normalization across scales?** -- Not great (-- [code2](https://pastebin.com/NcPCStBs)):

[image]

On right-hand side we see the best case using limited number of samples, on left we see the resampling implementation. Clearly due to inherently poor resolution of small number of samples, our norms don't do well for low scales - but the recomputed variant at least maintains a *mean* norm approximately constant across them.

More interestingly, the resampled one suddenly appears quadratic after $\log_2(a)=6$; what's the deal? Recall "It begins ... at scale $a=64$"; this is when we resample with *more samples than in original* (`int_psi`):

[image]

whose `diff` is

[image]

- In 1LR we see `int_psi` at `scale=256` is resampling the same values from `int_psi` multiple times, which manifests as zeros in `diff` (2LR).
- Next we square the values to get an idea of the L2 norm, and compare against the L2-normalized values in 3LR; we find normed values blowing unnormed values out of water. Is this excessive, or appropriate?
- Compare against recomputed at same scale; in 4LR, we at least see recomputed's shape - it's no longer negligible. This suggests the resampling to be *overestimating* wavelet amplitude, and since in norm computation this is significantly offset by half the values being zero due to `diff`, then the overestimation must be great.

How great? We can compare peak wavelet amplitudes across scales of the unnormed resampled `diff(int_psi_256)` and recomputed `w` (`morlet2/scale`); norming changes both by the same factor (`*sqrt(scale)`), won't make a difference.

[image]

Surely enough, again at $a=64$ we see critical behavior; peak amplitude of resampled *saturates* at a minimum, whereas the recomputed continues to decrease. The difference at $a=256$ is more than great enough (~12db=4x, if squared -> 16x) to offset the zeros in `diff`, hence why the L2 norm grows.

But notice the *L1 norm* remains well-behaved at higher scales. To find out why, we must precisely compare the proportion of zeros with the overestimation factor. We already know latter to be 4x; for former, I took a non-flat region (otherwise it's zeros anyway) and found ratio of zeros to number of samples: *0.75*. Which means, 1 in 4 values are non-zero, and each are 4x greater ... the exact proportion needed to retain the L1 norm.

That zeros proportion isn't very clear from above plots - so instead, dots:

[image]

---

**If `diff` undoes `cumsum`, why do either at all?**

Good question. In fact, by ridding of both, I found the quality degradation (zipper) effect disappear:

[image]

But something else also disappears - the high frequency scales (left), and the sign flips (I undid this by removing minus at `coef = -`). I partly offset this by replacing `* sqrt(scale)` by `1 / sqrt(scale)` (right), but that gets us to the L2 normed case (`1 / scale` is overkill), and is a baseless modification in light of everything found so far. So can it be done? Sure, one can implement without the `int-diff` dance, but I won't be exploring it here.

---

**Caveat: *effective* norm**

Recall, `conv` gets trimmed to `len(x)`, so the *entire* wavelet may not participate in computation, whereas above computations assume otherwise. The assumption is truer the longer `x` is - but here's what happens if `len(x) == 512`, with same wavelet `precision=10` (2^10=1024 `int_psi`), compared against recomputed wavelet:

[image]

A mess! *Both* distort significantly, possibly implying it's inherent to great enough scales pinned against short signals. A simple workaround is zero-padding the signal, but I wouldn't vouch for it without understanding the caveats (which I don't for wavelets, but do for [DFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70498/50076)).

Furthermore, note that the norm isn't only per-scale, but also *per-shift* ($b$); less of the wavelet is in the signal when it's just entering as opposed to when its center is at signal's center.

But keeping it per-scale, I confess I cheated in the earlier example with $f=4$; initially I picked $f=1$, but the L1 norm plot didn't look nice, and I didn't understand why. Since now I do, here are both L1 and L2 per scale for $f=1,64$:

[image]

Compare against earlier plot; note how the left modes (low scales) of both norms are unaffected, only the high scale (low frequency) ones are now much greater (L2) and lower (L1), just as expected.

---

**Caveat 2: `* step` doesn't do the L1-normalizing**

Instead, it results from `diff`ing the resampled integrated wavelet; the `* step` only sets the correct initial scale, and can be omitted without losing the norm. This does *not* happen with recomputing the wavelet, or resampling the unintegrated wavelet.

(Note that recomputed `scipy.signal.morlet2` is L2-normalized, but only because it's [explicitly](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/signal/wavelets.py#L385) normalized; the `diff`-resample-`int` is "self-normalized").